# Как определить регистр символа

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, как определить регистр символа. Именно определить, а не изменить. Есть ли какая-нибудь функция? Самый простой метод в лоб - это два массива с верхний и нижним регистром, после проверка на вхождение. Есть ли путь проще?

Comment: Хорошо, что еще никто не догадался регулярное выражение использовать))

Comment: @lampa, к сожалению, нет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/705517/207618

Answer (score 13):

Например, так можно:

```
 var symbol = 's';
 var isUpperCase = symbol.toUpperCase()==symbol;
 alert(!!isUpperCase);  // true - верхний регистр, false - нижний
```

Comment: Благодарю. Пожалуй, воспользуюсь Вашим вариантом!

Answer (score 6):

На ум пришло 2 идеи:

1. Сравнивать диапазон ASCII кодов символов, если входит в диапазон - значит верхний регистр, иначе нижний. Сложность в том, что тут придется учитывать разные кодировки, или приводить символ\текст к нужной.
2. Воспользоваться функцие приводящей к верхнему\нижнему регистру. Пример допустимый для PHP:

`function isUpper($str)
{
    if ($str === strtoupper($str)) return true;
    else return false;
}`

В JS у строки есть метод - toUpperCase().

Comment: Первый вариант, мне кажется, наиболее правильный. Только "иначе нижний" не совсем верно, может быть вовсе не буква. И быть внимательным, т.к. букву ё вечно все недолюбливают.

Comment: первый вариант не очень, время 8-ми битных кодировок уже давно прошло.

    >a="ёлки палки. Что такое с этим ё".toUpperCase()
    "ЁЛКИ ПАЛКИ. ЧТО ТАКОЕ С ЭТИМ Ё"

Comment: @pincher1519 чем плохо ?

    "ёлки палки. Что такое с этим ё".split('').map(function(v,i) {
       if (v.toUpperCase()==v.toLowerCase()) return  '#';
       return v==v.toUpperCase()?"U":"l"} 
    );

Comment: А разве нельзя сравнить, если ch >= 'A' и ch <= 'Z', то заглавная?

Comment: @pincher1519, получится, что Щ - это строчная буква

Comment: @fike, само собой нужно это ещё сделать и для русского алфавита, и отдельно для буквы ё.

Comment: @pincher1519 

> А разве нельзя сравнить, если ch >= 'A' и ch <= 'Z', то заглавная?

сравните подобным образом utf8 строку и получите национальную индийскую премию по программированию.

> само собой нужно это ещё сделать и для русского алфавита, и отдельно для буквы ё.

зачем это все если есть `.toUpperCase` ?

Comment: @pincher1519 и ять еще не забыть, ага

Comment: Потому все сайты и тупят по несколько секунд, что горе программисты гоняют данные из одного регистра в другой, ради банальной проверки.
Вы случаем не складываете числа интегралами?

Comment: @pincher1519 какая такая банальная проверка ? вы предлагаете 500 условий вставить на каждый язык,  .toUpperCase() написана на си и учитывает правила перевода символа в utf8 для всех языков. Горе программист это вы - вместо того чтобы использовать стандартную функцию, городите велосипед. (а вы случайно не складываете числа ассемблерными вставками ?), кстати заметьте - я свои слова подтверждаю кодом, а вы даже не пробовали свою процедуру написать, ибо когда попробуете - увидите насколько ужасна она будет при банальном требовании совместимости английский, немецкий, русский.

Answer (score 0):

На днях столкнулся с такой же задачей. Предлагаю свою идею. В ходе написание скрипта были учтены непереводимые в регистр символы, цифры, пробел. При определении ввода верхнего регистра проверяю последний введенный символ.

Ну в общем чего ходить вокруг да около вот функция которая принимает объект и уже на типу объекта берет значение для проверки.

```
/** 
* return boolean
* true - using Caps Lock
* false - not using Caps Lock
**/
function checkingUp(_obj){

    var symbol = '';
    var type = _obj[0].tagName;

    switch(type)
    {
        case "INPUT" :
            symbol = String(_obj.val());
                break;
    }

    if(symbol == ''){
        return false;
    }        

    symbol = symbol.substr(symbol.length - 1, (symbol.length));        

    if($.isNumeric(symbol)){
        return false;    
    }

    var newSymbol = symbol.toLowerCase();

    if(symbol != newSymbol){
        return true;    
    }

    return false;

}
```

Функция принимает String значение для проверки.

```
/** 
* return boolean
* true - using Caps Lock
* false - not using Caps Lock
**/
function checkingUp(_obj){

    var symbol = _obj;

    if(symbol == ''){
        return false;
    }        

    symbol = symbol.substr(symbol.length - 1, (symbol.length));        

    if($.isNumeric(symbol)){
        return false;    
    }

    var newSymbol = symbol.toLowerCase();

    if(symbol != newSymbol){
        return true;    
    }

    return false;

}
```

Функция может быть использована для проверки вводимого значения в поле Password, примерный код проверки с использованием вышеизложенной функции прилаживая ниже . . .

```
    $("#login-form input[type=password]").each(function(){

        // после поля ввода пароля расположен span с логотипом капчи, скрытый стилями css
        var iconCapsLock = $(this).parent().find('.capslock');

        $(this).bind('keyup', function(){

             if(checkingUp($(this))){
                iconCapsLock.show();
             }
             else{
                iconCapsLock.hide();
             }
        });

        $(this).bind('blur', function(){
            iconCapsLock.hide();
        });

});
```

И под конец пример HTML верстки с полем для проверки

```
    <div class="form-group relative">
        <input type="password"name="RegistrationForm[user_password]" class="input-lg form-control">
<span class="help-block"><span aria-hidden="true" class="capslock glyphicon glyphicon-text-height"></span></span>
    </div>
```

Надеюсь, что мой совет поможет нуждающимся ))

Answer (score 0):

Как вам такой вариант?

```
checked_val.charAt(0).matches("A-Z"); //Верх. регистр

checked_val.charAt(0).matches("a-z"); //Нижн. регистр
```

Если "для английских не прокатит"

```
if (targetId.charAt(0).toUpperCase() == targetId.charAt(0)) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    ...

  }
```

Comment: Для неанглийских не прокатит

Comment: А копировать чужие ответы в этом же вопросе - некрасиво.

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение:

```
   function strUpAndDown(str){
      var newStr = '';
    for(var i =0; i < str.length;i++){
      if(str[i].toLowerCase() === str[i]){
       newStr += str[i].toUpperCase();       
     }else {
       newStr += str[i].toLowerCase();
     }
   }
    return newStr;
  }
```

Comment: Вроде инвертировать не просили?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function whatCase(ch) {
  var u = ch.toUpperCase(), l = ch.toLowerCase()
  return u !== l ? ch === u ? 'upper' : 'lower' : 'not-a-letter'
}

document.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  document.querySelector("output").innerHTML = e.target.value.split("").map(function (ch) {
    return "<span class=" + whatCase(ch) + ">" + ch + "</span>"
  }).join("")
})
```

```css
.upper { color: blue; }
.lower { color: green; }
.not-a-letter { color: red; }
input, output { display: block; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<input>
<output>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun(string) {
  
    for (let char of string)
        if (char != char.toLowerCase(char)) 
            // действие        
        else
            // действие

    return //действие

}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]